# IIS cannot write file if called from remote, only from the server

Tags: c#, .net, iis, file-permissions

I am running a web api on a IIS on Windows Server 2012 R2.

The application has a controller, that on a get request will write to a file on a network share.

If I access the site from a browser on the server it works fine, however if I access the site from my own computer, I get an exception saying that I do not have permission to write to the file.

Users are authenticated against the networks AD, and I am using the same user on both my computer and on the server.

It seems that IIS is handling the request as an other user if I call it from the server, but I have not been able to figure out how I can change this so I can write the file from another host as well.

The code that is giving the exception is using a `StreamWriter`

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(_filePathName))
{
    writer.WriteLine(GetSetting("PROTECTED_KMDHeader"));
    writer.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable impersonation. See this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc730708(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I enabled impersonation, however the result was the same. I could generate the file from the server but not from my own computer.
But without impersonation enabled, what contexts is IIS using when I try to access the filesystem? because it must differ from the two use cases of either being on the server or accessing the server from another computer.

Comment: IIS is using the identity given in the application pool. By default, it is set to "DefaultAppPool". see http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities